# IE, and iframe.elementFromPoint not passing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

**Update:** Fiddle Demonstration -- http://jsfiddle.net/7tfbtso6/2/ -- Most of the settings work in chrome and firefox, but the only one that works in IE is Left-align: 105px. I do have overflow set to hidden on html and body, but this makes no difference. IE will not work if the element is not visible on screen. And `overflow: visible` on html and body give the effect of auto and no effect on the problem here.

My site uses two contentEditable divs.
[image: demo graphic]

#### #rInput is part of the document.

#### #rSyntax is part of an iframe under (z-index) #rInput.

In every browser I've tried so far, except IE (I'll get to that in a moment.), I'm able to determine what element is contained within the iframe using elementFromPoint().

In IE's case, this is only possible if they're not overlapping which isn't possible because a secondary purpose, as the name implies, is to provide syntax-highlighting.

The IE IFrame has to be visible, **on screen**, not obstructed by any objects. I've tried `display: none;`, `visibility: hidden`, and pushing it down in a div with overflow: hidden, but all of these attempts cause it not to work. I've also tried setting the height and width to small proportions.

If any of these could work, I could use two copies of rSyntax, one on top (z-index), hidden somehow, for mouse events and one for syntax highlighting.

Most of these solutions work in every browser **but** IE. The IE box simply demands that it be on top.

"Flickering" it with css (display, visibility, pointer-events) seems awfully hacky (and just plain awful). I haven't really tried to implement it because it seems like a last resort.

The problem is further complicated because I'm trying to capture clicks and mouseovers, for different purposes (clicks for finding content, mouseovers for tooltips--created with a div mimicking `attr("title")`.

I've briefly tried placing the iframe on top (z-index) of the div, but there's no way to intercept the clicks and pass to the lower object because it runs in to the same problem.

Here's the script I'm using to get the objects, partly in case it's useful to anyone.

```
$(document).on("mousemove", "#rInput", function (e) {
    $element = $(document.getElementById('frSyntax').contentDocument.elementFromPoint(e.pageX+$("#rInputContainer").scrollLeft()-10,e.pageY+$("#rInputContainer").scrollTop()-12));
    if ($element.is("span") && $element.attr("title") && $element.attr("title").length) {
        $("#syntip").text($element.attr("title"));
        $("#syntip").css({"top": e.pageY+10, "left": e.pageX, "display": "inline-block"});
    } else {
        $("#syntip").hide();
    }
});
```

I have considered transparency, and that works for this element, because it's small, but I use a similar setup with a large element that takes up more than 50% of the screen, there would be problems.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: @DonRhummy http://jsfiddle.net/7tfbtso6/1/ Works perfectly in chrome/firefox, but in IE ("Edge"), the only option that works is the one that moves it to a visible region on screen. I do have `html, body`'s `overflow: hidden` but this make no difference to IE, if the element is off screen, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

After many frustrating efforts, I concluded that pushing the top (`z-index`-wise) element offscreen was the only solution for IE/Edge. Flickering it with `display: none` causes some properties I needed, like width, to not be accurate.

Just make sure you push it farther than the element will ever be. My application is sidescrolling so I merely needed to place the css `top` to something like 2000.